# PHP- Convert String to Datetime Format

Tags: php, datetime

I have a string - `15/09/2015 12:00` - [Day/Month/Year] Format, I want to convert it to Year-Month-Day [mysql date time format].

I tried to use the following:

```
$myDateTime = $myDateTime->createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '15/09/2015 12:00');
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

but it throws an internal server error.

Comment: date('Y-m-d',strtotime('15/09/2015 12:00')) use this

Comment: echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('15/09/2015 12:00')) result 1970-01-01 05:30.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia: `xx/xx/xxxx` format belongs to `mm/dd/yyyy`, thats why strtotime() will return `false`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `DateTime` class to call function `createFromFormat` static function

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '15/09/2015 12:00');
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Tested and giving Output:

```
2015-09-15 12:00
```

Comment: Why should OP *try this* ?

Comment: Explained @Rizier123. Do you want anything more?

Comment: @Manwal nice job dude